# Special characters in QR code

Tags: qrcode

I am trying to read a list of URLs from a file and create QR codes for them. If they contain a `#` like in the example, I get an

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \qr@texttoencode

error. Is it possible to make this work without having to edit the input file and escape the special characters there?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{filecontents*}{urls.txt}
http://example.org/foo#bar
\end{filecontents*}

\def\loadurls#1{%
    \newread\file
    \openin\file=#1
    \begingroup\endlinechar=-1
    \loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \read\file to \fileline
    \qrcode{\fileline}
    \repeat
    \endgroup
    \closein\file
}

\begin{document}
    \loadurls{urls.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Thank you!

Comment: Oops. Only `\catcode35=11` and `\ifx\fileline\empty\else\qrcode{\fileline}\fi` are necessary. Sorry for the overcomplicated suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using `csvsimple`. Look at the section *3.6 Special Characters* of the `csvsimple` documentation for other options to escape the  special characters. Here I used the `respect sharp=true` to interpret # as a normal character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{urls.txt}
http://example.org/foo#bar
http://www.ctan.org
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
\csvreader[nohead,respect sharp=true]{urls.txt}{}{\qrcode{\csvcoli}\quad}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\readstring` rather than `\read`. By the way, `\newread` should go outside the definition of `\loadurls` (and you should use a different name than `\file`).

Here's an `expl3` version:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.dat}
http://example.org/foo#bar
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594413/special-characters-in-qr-code#594426
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\loadurls}{m}
 {
  \patheticpat_loadurls:n { #1 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_patheticpat_loadurls_ior

\cs_new_protected:Nn \patheticpat_loadurls:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_patheticpat_loadurls_ior { #1 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_patheticpat_loadurls_ior
   {
    \qrcode{##1}\par\medskip
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\loadurls{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

[image]